# Should the database connexion Context be a Singleton in a .net core app using MongoDB?

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, singleton, repository-pattern

Lots of code I've seen use the Repository pattern for the database connexion, injecting dependencies with `addTransient`, to get a unique Repository per request.

```
service.AddTransient<IRepository, Repository>();
```

The problem is that the database connexion would then be (re)created on each request if the database's Context is called in the Repository's Constructor, isn't it?

```
// Repository.cs
---------------------------------------------------------------

public Repository(IOptions<Settings> settings)
{
    _context = new Context(settings);
}


// Context.cs
---------------------------------------------------------------

public Context(IOptions<Settings> settings)
{
    _client = new MongoClient(settings.Value.ConnectionString);
    _database = _client.GetDatabase(...);
}
```

Should the database's Context be a Singleton instead?

```
service.AddSingleton(new Context(...));
```

Or should the MongoDB Context be passed with `AddDbContext<Context>`?

Answer (score 0):

If you call the constructore of an object: Yes, a new instance is created.

Whether or not to use a SingleTon is basically just a matter of your own use of these objects.

If your repository is only relying upon the input only and not stored data within the repository, making it a SingleTon makes perfect sense. However, you should consider how you'd access the data within the context; if each call should open a new connection or use the same if possible.

But most importantly in my opinion: You will know the answer yourself, if you see any benefit to your application from either solution that's what you should try aiming for. Changing the implementation to be a SingleTon does not make much sense, if you do not benefit from the pattern.